# How to list details according to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord

I have a properties tables with fields name,price, start_date, end_date.
i want to list properties between start_date and end_date.
I wrote query like this, but i am not getting correct  output.

I want to convert date format like 02/12/2015 to 2015/12/02(as it is in database format).

`@properties = Property.where("properties.start_date >= ? AND properties.end_date <= ? ",params[:start_date], params[:end_date]).order(updated_at: :desc)`

How to list by date?

Any help is appreciatable

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `but i am not getting correct output.` can you explain a little more about it?

Comment: i want to convert date in this query. which is not happening now(ie;to database format and needed to check)

Comment: `@properties = Property.where("DATE(properties.start_date) >= ? AND DATE(properties.end_date) <= ? ",params[:start_date], params[:end_date]).order(updated_at: :desc)`  - Are you looking to compare based on dates, you can try this.

Comment: SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE (DATE(properties.start_date) >= '04/01/2016' AND DATE(properties.end_date) <= '04/04/2016' )  ORDER BY `properties`.`updated_at` DESC

Comment: i am getting like this, date is not converting here

Comment: can you show how your `params[:start_date]` and `params[:end_date]` looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse dates first to get them in correct format. Try something like this:

```
start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])

@properties = Property.where("properties.start_date >= ? AND properties.end_date <= ? ",start_date, end_date).order(updated_at: :desc)
```